# Is it Undefined Behavior to call GL commands without a current context?

Tags: opengl

In many docs, they'll regularly tell you that you must have a context current in a thread to use any GL commands. However, what *specifically* happens when there's no current context?

On Windows, [wglMakeCurrent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-wglmakecurrent) documents that "A thread must set a current rendering context before calling any OpenGL functions. Otherwise, all OpenGL calls are ignored.", but I couldn't find any similar statements for the other major operating systems. A quick test program on Linux/X11 also seemed to "do nothing" without actually segfaulting the program or anything like that.

So my question is this: Is it actually Undefined Behavior to call GL without a current context? Or is it just "unspecified" without actually being UB?

Comment: This question seems academic. Whether such calls are UB, unspecified, a no-op, or anything else, what they most certainly will be is *not useful*. Without a context, such calls would be meaningless, so does it really matter what some documentation says happens? Even if they're harmless no-ops, just write your code so they don't happen.

Comment: Academic or not, I want to know. Some of us care about UB.